# Allowing only one answer in Google forms

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, google-forms, uniqueidentifier

Hi I want to create a Google form which i can collect student data,
And i want to make a way to allow my students to only enter one answer one time

in example I want to use this method in the question which asks for the admission number, admission number is a uniqe number which will not be repeated. So if a student enter an admission number that is already entered , I want them to see an error message with "The admission number has been already used"

Comment: Why don't you give/send the admission number to each one personally? You can then discard any submissions that are later than the first one.

Comment: I guess students are not required to log into Google when responding to the form? Otherwise it would just be a matter of checking `Limit to 1 response` on the form settings. If that's not the case, you could also use an Apps Script [onFormSubmit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/form-trigger-builder#onFormSubmit()) trigger to edit the response validation for the item in which the `admission number` is entered, adding the admission number that was just entered as invalid for future submissions. I'd consider posting an answer explaining this if you think it could help.

Comment: " you could also use an Apps Script onFormSubmit trigger to edit the response validation for the item in which the admission number is entered," This is a good idea ,can you explain more about this

Comment: I posted an answer explaining how this can be done. Let me know if you if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue:

Avoid multiple form responses to be submitted with the same value for a specific form item.

#### Workflow:

- In order to avoid certain responses to be submitted, you have to use some kind of data validation for the `Admission number` item, as shown in [Set rules for your form](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3378864?hl=en).
- This data validation should be updated every time a form response is submitted, since the newly submitted `Admission number` should be forbidden in future responses.
- In order to update this validation every time the form is submitted, you could use an Apps Script [onFormSubmit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/form-trigger-builder#onformsubmit) trigger, which would then fire a function on every form submission. Let's call this function `updateDataValidation`.
- The `onFormSubmit` trigger can be installed either manually, following [these steps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually), or [programmatically](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically), via executing the function `createTrigger` from the code sample below once.

Every time `updateDataValidation` fires, it should do the following:

- Find all the previous responses for your `Admission number` item. You could first retrieve all form responses via [Form.getResponses()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getResponses()) and then find the responses related to your item by checking its title (see [Item.getTitle()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item#getTitle())).
- Transform the array of admission numbers retrieved in previous step into a regex pattern that can be used for the data validation, which could be like this: `^{number1}$|^{number2}$|^{number3}$...`.
- Use [TextValidation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/text-validation) in order to update the validation rules for your item.

#### Code sample:

```
function updateDataValidation(e) {
  const itemTitle = "Admission number"; // Name of the form item. Change accordingly
  const errorMessage = "The admission number has been already used.";
  const form = e ? e.source : FormApp.getActiveForm();
  const responses = form.getResponses();
  const admissionNumbers = responses.map(response => {
    return response.getItemResponses().find(itemResponse => {
      return itemTitle === itemResponse.getItem().getTitle();
    });
  }).map(itemResponse => itemResponse.getResponse());
  const numbersPattern = admissionNumbers.map(number => `^${number}\$`).join("|");
  const item = form.getItems().find(item => item.getTitle() === itemTitle);
  let validation = FormApp.createTextValidation()
                          .setHelpText(errorMessage)
                          .requireTextDoesNotMatchPattern(numbersPattern)
                          .build();
  item.asTextItem().setValidation(validation);
}

function createTrigger() {
  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('updateDataValidation')
    .forForm(form)
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create();
}
```

#### Notes:

- In the code sample above, the item `Admission number` is assumed to be named `Admission number`. Change that from the code if that's not the case.
- In the code sample above, the item `Admission number` is assumed to be a text item, like `Short answer`.

Comment: Oops I couldnt do my job according to your @lamblichus instructions, Im new to Google scripts and coding so can you give me the instructions more simply. step by step and can you tell me clearly which parts should i replace in the code 

Should i create 2 scripts?  1 with [onFormSubmit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/form-trigger-builder#onformsubmit) and another one with the code you gave ?? 

its not clear, Can you explain it more clearly

Comment: @AshirwadaManamudali Only one script is needed, in which you would add the code I provided. So do the following: (1) Copy the code I provided, and (2) Run `createTrigger` once (this will install the `onFormSubmit` trigger - which will fire `updateDataValidation` whenever the form is submitted - there is no additional code necessary). Let me know if you need more instructions or details.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Should i replace **Item Title** with the question?
and is there a place to add my form ID Which is `1FAIpQLSdVIS7-lLBkoLsAlzzm0XWyMiOD2FvvdUc6uj5aWTqRBsZTWQ`

Comment: What are the items that i should replace in order to customize the code to work accordingly to my form

Comment: @AshirwadaManamudali If your script is [bound](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) to your Form, you don't need to specify an ID: `FormApp.getActiveForm()` refers to the Form to which the script is bound. You should just replace `itemTitle` (currently `Admission number`, see line 2 of the function `updateDataValidation`) with the name of the item in your form. Also, if the script is not bound to the Form, but standalone, you should replace both instances of `FormApp.getActiveForm()` with `FormApp.openById("YOUR_FORM_ID")`.

Comment: @AshirwadaManamudali Was this useful? Do you need further clarification?

Comment: i did as you said but couldn't solve the issue

Comment: @AshirwadaManamudali `couldn't solve the issue` Could you provide more details? Have you been able to install the trigger? (look at the `Triggers` tab) Is the function `updateDataValidation` running when the form is submitted? Is it giving any error? (look at the `Executions` tab).